# Solving differential equation using undetermined coefficient with overlap root

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$y''-4y'+8y=e^{2x}$$  I try to solve differential equation using undetermined coefficient, 
I found homogeneous solution is $2 \pm 2i$, 
so $y_c=e^{2x}(A\cos 2x+B \sin 2x)$.

I use undetermined coefficient, and guess the particular solution is
$y=Ae^{2x} x^2$, is $e^{2x}A\cos 2x$ and $e^{2x}$ in $y_p$ overlap? Is my undetermined coefficient true? thanks

Comment: What do you understand by `overlap`?

Comment: try for $$y_p=Ae^{2x}(B+C\cos(2x))$$

Comment: You need try $y=Ae^{2x}$.

Comment: As myglasses proposed to try $y=Ae^{2x}$. Your ODE is not resonant, hence there is no need to multiply with $x^2$.

Comment: @Vixf use the method of annihalator operator then you will see how you can assume the particular solution using undetermined method